# How to layer one window on top of another with transparency(Overlay) or how to do aplha-blending on two windows using directx?

Tags: c#, directx, overlay

I am trying to achieve alpha blending of two windows Like  I have one window that contains an image and another window that contains webpage. I want to alpha blend these two windows so that it gives an overlay effect and I want the top window to be transparent so that window underneath it could be seen. Later I want to save this in to the video(Preferably using direct x). I have read several tutorials over the internet regarding the direct x alpha blending but have not been able to find what I want to achieve. Any example/source code to achieve this or any pointer towards the right direction would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found an answer myself. Further research lead me to [**This,This**](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWinFormLayeredWindow-23cdc375/view/Discussions) thread which was exactly what i was looking for. This might be useful to someone else and might save a lot of head banging on research.